# Erro ao utilizar .stream().filter no JAVA

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, filter, jee

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação na qual tem como objetivo criar uma lista que respeita a condição de ser do tipo = "unidade". No código abaixo, crio a lista e a partir de uma função tento gerar essa lista.

**codigo da classe ProductMovement**

package teste1;

```
public class ProductMovement {
    private int id;
    private String nome;

    public ProductMovement(int id, String nome) {

        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public ProductMovement() {


    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

}
```

**codigo da classe Teste1**

```
package teste1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import teste1.ProductMovement;



public class Teste {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static  List<ProductMovement> filterFractionedMovements(List<ProductMovement> reservMovements) {

        return (List<ProductMovement>) reservMovements.stream().filter(px -> px.getNome().equals("unidade"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // Creating a list 

            List<ProductMovement> pro = Arrays.asList(new ProductMovement(1,"unidade"),
                    new ProductMovement(2,"caixa"),  
                    new ProductMovement(3,"unidade"),
                    new ProductMovement(4,"caixa"));

            //Stream<ProductMovement> ProductMovements = pro.stream();
            //Integer idTipoProduto = ProductMovements.filter(px -> px.getNome().equals("unidade")).mapToInt(px -> px.getId()).sum();
            //System.out.println(idTipoProduto);    

            //lista somente 
            List<ProductMovement> lista = filterFractionedMovements(pro);
            lista.forEach(element -> System.out.println(element));

    }
}
```

**Mensagem de erro:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2 cannot be cast to java.util.List
>     at teste1.Teste.filterFractionedMovements(Teste.java:17)    at
>   teste1.Teste.main(Teste.java:34)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todos os métodos de Stream retornam outro Stream. Para transformar de volta em uma lista, você precisa usar um Collector:

```
<Seu stream>.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: contudo tenho de somente criar a lista com os objetos curso descriçao/nome tem "unidade"

Comment: esse filtro não funciona:  filter(px -> px.getNome().equals("unidade")

Comment: Deveria funcionar, o único problema que eu achei no seu código foi a falta do Collector após o filtro. De resto, seu código faz exatamente o que você quer.

Comment: @alexjosesilva Se usar `filter` junto com `collect`, como indicado, funciona sim: https://ideone.com/AcUvLr - Talvez vc tenha feito alguma outra coisa que não foi indicada na pergunta, não sei...

Comment: @hkotsubo é possível inserir duas condições no filter ? Tipo or(ou) ??

Comment: @alexjosesilva Dentro do filter vc pode colocar quantas condições quiser: https://ideone.com/c6cbPN - A maioria dos casos que vejo tem uma ou duas condições, mas na verdade a função pode ser tão complexa quanto vc precisar.

Comment: @hkotsubo pode informar dois exemplos de condições no stream.filter

Comment: @alexjosesilva No link do comentário anterior (https://ideone.com/c6cbPN) tem um exemplo - está na linha 20

Comment: posso usar assim :  .filter((px -> px.getNome().equals("unidade")) or (px -> px.getNome().equals("casa")))

Comment: @alexjosesilva O "or" do Java é usando `||` -> `filter((px -> px.getNome().equals("unidade")) || (px -> px.getNome().equals("casa")))`